# Вывести документ эксель в консоль C#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Необходимо вывести лист из экселя в консоль в виде таблички. С моим кодом выводится вся страница целиком, в одну кашу. Можно ли как то вывести как в экселе?С соблюдением объединенных ячеек. Вот моя табличка [image: отсюда берем данные]. Вот что выводится в консоль после моего кода [image: каша данных в консоли]

```
private static void ReadExcel(string path)
         {
        using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(path)))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet firstWorksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

            for (int i = 1; i <= firstWorksheet.Dimension.Columns; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= firstWorksheet.Dimension.Rows; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(firstWorksheet.Cells[j,i].Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: у вас проблема в консоли таблтчку нарисовать? Скачайте, например, Far и в нем  потренируйтесь

Comment: да, вы правильно поняли, у меня проблема нарисовать табличку в консоли. Так что мы будем с этим делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как я данных не вижу и не смогу протестировать, то готовый вариант не подскажу, но помогу продвинуться в вопросе. Первое, что надо сделать, это выводить построчно, а не поколоночно. Сейчас у вас (хоть вы и не видите) таблица развернута на 90 градусов. Второе - добавить пробелов и переносов строк.

```cs
for (int i = 1; i <= firstWorksheet.Dimension.Rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= firstWorksheet.Dimension.Columns; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(firstWorksheet.Cells[j, i].Value + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Это уже будет больше похоже на правду.

Следующими шагами можно попробовать вычитать таблицу в массив строк, посчитать максимальную длину для содержимого каждой колонки, дорисовать черточек, расставить отступы и т.д.

Comment: спасибо, как раз то, что я искал!